# Differential equation's flow

Tags: differential-equations

I'm struggling to solve the following problem:
Find the image of $(1,0)$ vector in $(0,0)$ point under the action of system's flow:
\begin{cases}
x'= e^{3x}-e^{4y}  \\
y'= e^{x}-e^{y}
\end{cases}
I tried to solve it and haven't come to any good result. For instance, we know, how to find flow for linear case via
$ e^{tA} $ without solving it. Is it possible to do something like this in my case? Thanks for any help.